# How to drop NA variables in a data frame by row

Tags: r, dplyr, vegan

Here is my data frame:

```
 structure(list(Q = c(NA, 346.86, 166.95, 162.57, NA, NA, NA, 
        266.7), L = c(18.93, NA, 15.72, 39.51, NA, NA, NA, NA), C = c(NA, 
        23.8, NA, 8.47, 20.89, 18.72, 14.94, NA), X = c(40.56, NA, 26.05, 
        3.08, 23.77, 59.37, NA, NA), W = c(29.47, NA, NA, NA, 36.08, 
        NA, 27.34, 28.19), S = c(NA, 7.47, NA, NA, 18.64, NA, 25.34, 
        NA), Y = c(NA, 2.81, 0, NA, NA, 21.18, 10.83, 12.19), H = c(0, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -8L), .Names = c("Q", "L", "C", "X", "W", "S", "Y", "H"))
```

Each row has 4 variables that are NAs, now I want to do the same operations to **every row**:

1. Drop those 4 varibles that are NAs
2. Calculate diversity for the rest 4 variables (it's just some computations involved with the rest, here I use `diversity()` from `vegan`)
3. Append the output to a new data frame

But the problem is:

1. How to do drop NA variables using `dplyr`? I don't know whether `select()` can make it.
2. How to apply operations to every row of a data frame?

It seems that `drop_na()` will remove the entire row for my dataset, any suggestion?

Comment: Do you really need to remove the NA or replace it with 0 and calculate the `diversity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` it may be better to `gather` into 'long' format and then `spread` it back.  Assuming that we have exactly 4 non-NA elements per row, create a row index with `rownames_to_column` (from `tibble`), `gather` (from `tidyr`) into 'long' format, remove the NA elements, grouped by row number ('rn'), change the 'key' values to common values and then `spread` it to wide' format

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
res <- rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% 
      gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
      group_by(rn) %>%  
      mutate(key = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
      spread(key, val) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      select(-rn)
res
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#      A     B     C     D
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  18.9  40.6 29.5   0   
#2 347    23.8  7.47  2.81
#3 167    15.7 26.0   0   
#4 163    39.5  8.47  3.08
#5  20.9  23.8 36.1  18.6 
#6  18.7  59.4 21.2   0   
#7  14.9  27.3 25.3  10.8 
#8 267    28.2 12.2   0   

diversity(res)
#      1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#1.0533711 0.3718959 0.6331070 0.7090783 1.3517680 0.9516232 1.3215712 0.4697572
```

---

Regarding the `diversity` calculation, we can `replace` NA with 0 and apply on the whole dataset i.e.

```
library(vegan)
diversity(replace(df1, is.na(df1), 0))
#[1] 1.0533711 0.3718959 0.6331070 0.7090783
#[5] 1.3517680 0.9516232 1.3215712 0.4697572
```

as we get the same output as in the first solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I too find that the simplest solution is to replace NA with 0, however, your first solution is also important to me as it provides me a general method to solve this kind of problems

Comment: Yes, replacing `NA` with 0 will give the same result as removing `NA`: zeros do not influence `diversity()` result.

Comment: @JariOksanen  Thank you for confirming it.